# convolution, trapezoidal distribution pdf

Tags: probability, combinations

$X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables.

- $X$ is equal likely to be any value of $\{0,1,2,\ldots,m\}$.
- $Y$ is equal likely to be any value of $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

Define $Z=X+Y$. What's the pmf of $Z$? (Assume $m<n$)

The solution given on the handout is:

$P(Z=i)=\frac{i+1}{(m+1)(n+1))}, 0\leqslant i\leqslant m\tag{1}$

$P(Z=i)=\frac{m+1}{(m+1)(n+1)}, m+1\leqslant i\leqslant n\tag{2}$

$P(Z=i)=\frac{m+n-i}{(m+1)(n+1)}, n+1\leqslant i\leqslant n+m\tag{3}$

My question is why the numerator in (2) is not $n-(m+1)+1=n-m$.

The reason why I think it should be $n-m$ is because there are $n-m$ numbers between $m+1$ and $n$. Similar reasoning that the the numerator in (3) should be $n+m-(n+1)+1=m$.

Could any one help me this out? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure the ranges shouldn't be $0-m$ and $0-n$?

Comment: @Mick A, ah, right!! it should start from 0. thanks for the correction.

Comment: For (2): $P(Z=z) = \sum_{x=0}^m{P(X+Y=z\mid X=x)P(X=x)} = \sum_{x=0}^m{P(Y=z-x)P(X=x)} = \sum_{x=0}^m{\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{1}{m+1}} = \dfrac{m+1}{(m+1)(n+1)}.$

 So I think the solution they gave for (2) is correct.

Comment: @Mick A: I see. I didn't try by using conditional probability, by this way it's really quite clear. However, for the answers that I think is correct, my thought was there are (m+1)(n+1) possible values for Z=X+Y, so (m+1)(n+1) is in the denominator. and for the range of Z in (2), the value of Z could be any value of {m+1,...,n}, which has "n-m" possibilities, hence, the numerator is "n-m." Do you know where went wrong here? thanks!!

Comment: I got one more question. By using your approach, conditional probability, how to tell that the answer we got is for (2)? thanks~

Comment: When the denominator is the total number of ways to choose $m$ and $n$ (i.e $(m+1)(n+1)$) then the numerator has to be the number of ways to obtain the particular $z$ value - not the number of values within the range for (2). If you're not sure still, try setting $m=0$ and you'll see your method gives $P(Z=z)=\frac{n}{n+1}$, which obviously can't be right.

Comment: "How to tell that the answer we got is for (2)?" ... For the other ranges, the range of the summation is different. E.g. For (1), $Z=i$ is only possible if $0\leq X\leq i$. So we have $i$ as the upper limit on the summation instead of $m$. We get $\sum_{x=0}^i{\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{1}{m+1}} = \frac{i+1}{(n+1)(m+1)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

> $$
> P\left(X+Y=k\right){}={}\sum\limits_{y}P\left(X=k-y\,\,\bigg|\,Y=y\right)P\left(Y=y\right){}={}\sum\limits_{y}P\left(X=k-y\right)P\left(Y=y\right),
> $$

there are 3 cases:

(i) For $\,\,\,0\le i\le m$,
$$
P(X=i-y)P(Y=y){}={}\left\{\begin{array}{cc} \dfrac{1}{(m+1)(n+1)},&\,\,\mbox{for }\,\,0\le y\le i\\0,&\,\,\mbox{otherwise} \end{array}\right.
$$

(ii) For $\,\,\,m+1\le i\le n$,
$$
P(X=i-y)P(Y=y){}={}\left\{\begin{array}{cc} \dfrac{1}{(m+1)(n+1)},&\,\,\mbox{for }\,\,\,i-m\le y\le i\\0,&\,\,\mbox{otherwise} \end{array}\right.
$$

(iii) For $\,\,\,n+1\le i\le n+m$,
$$
P(X=i-y)P(Y=y){}={}\left\{\begin{array}{cc} \dfrac{1}{(m+1)(n+1)},&\,\,\mbox{for }\,\,i-m\le y\le n\\0,&\,\,\mbox{otherwise} \end{array}\right.
$$

These suggest that the probabilities should be:

> (i) For $\,\,\,0\le i\le m$,
> $$
> P(X+Y=i){}={}\dfrac{i+1}{(m+1)(n+1)}\,.
> $$
>
> (ii) For $\,\,\,m+1\le i\le n$,
> $$
> P(X+Y=i){}={}\dfrac{m+1}{(m+1)(n+1)}\,.
> $$
>
> (iii) For $\,\,\,n+1\le i\le n+m$,
> $$
> P(X+Y=i){}={}\dfrac{n+m-i+1}{(m+1)(n+1)}\,.
> $$

Comment: thanks so much for the detailed explanation. :)

Comment: @LizSugar, you are welcome.